# How can I delete lines consecutively in python text files?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a password generator that can delete lines consecutively off the password saver file. I've tried doing the same thing 4 times, but that doesn't work when trying to delete 4  lines after the 1st. Instead it deletes all the lines including that phrase of words. Here is some of my code:

```
with open("Password Saver.txt", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as file:
for line in file:
    if line.find(reason) != -1:
        for _ in range(4):
            next(file)
    else:
        Things2Keep = Things2Keep + (line.rstrip())
f = open("Password Saver.txt", "w")
f.write(Things2Keep)
```

Comment: **DO NOT** store passwords as plain text files

Comment: Why? Does it change a significant factor?

Comment: What do you mean by "consecutively"?

Comment: If i delete 1 line, i want it to delete 4 other lines after it.

Comment: You call `file.write()` on the first line.  So it's opened and not closed before being opened again.  Is it what you meant?

Comment: Yes, i did that so i could read the lines of the file before writing anything.

Comment: You're showing us code that works, and describing code that doesn't. I can't tell what you mean by *I've tried multiplying the code*. You're asking us to imagine what you have written and then tell you where the problem might be.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov This is clearly a beginner's toy program. I don't think  OP plans to use it in production.

Comment: Do you want to keep only the first occurrence and delete the following ones?

Comment: @nonDucor I also would like to delete the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
file.write("This is a placeholder.\n")
reason = "google"
with open("Password Saver.rtf",'rb') as IN:
    lines = IN.readlines()

with open("Password Saver.rtf",'wb') as OUT:
    for line in lines:
         if line.lower().find(reason.lower()) != -1:
             OUT.write(line)
```

Also, I think `.rtf` files better be opened as binary.

Comment: When I tried using this, it deleted all the lines in the file, even lines that weren't connected to the reason. Is there a way you could help me fix this?

Comment: `# If not found, as you wrote`

Comment: Try the edited version

Comment: How different it is from OP's version, except being *sort of* case-insensitive?

Comment: Just a bit safer…

Comment: When I tried your edited version, this error popped up: Type Error: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Answer (score 0):

So what I deduced from question and comments: remove the line that matches and four lines right after that.

##### Input

```
header
google
1
2
3
4
footer
```

##### Output

```
header
footer
```

##### Code

Normally I would introduce a counter to be incremented on every line after the match, but for this answer I prefer to go a bit crazy and skip lines as file-like object is an iterator:

```py
with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.find(reason) != -1:
            for _ in range(4):
                next(file)
        else:
            print(line.rstrip())
```

This is only to demonstrate the principle, adapt it for file manipulation yourself, as an exercise =)

Comment: Hi! I tried out your solution, and when the same reason occurs, it deletes the entire file, could you help me with this?

Comment: @AyanHaq, my code works just fine on my sample data, but it doesn't write anything to file.  Edit your question and add new version of the code.  Also your sample input and desired output.

Comment: Also, what does the encoding variable do?

Comment: I've edited the post, but I'm not that sure on what you meant by 'sample input and desired output'

Comment: @AyanHaq
Your new code finds a match, then skips 4 lines, then overwrites result file with that matching line.  If there's no match found, it does nothing, since there's nothing in code to handle that case (since you for some reason moved `else` clause to `for` loop).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'moved else clause to for loop' and also, the reason variable get turned into an integer and when I try to declare it as a string, it doesn't work.

Comment: There are obviously communication problems here, sorry.